# How to search String as Number using Named Query in Hibernate and Oracle?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, named-query

In Oracle, Datatype is vArchar and we have some ID's stored in format 0000123. From source we are getting ID as 123 or 1234 with preceding 0. In some cases data is stored simply as 123.

In SQL Query i can simply use

```
Select * from Table where ID = 123 (It wil fetch even if 000123 id is present)
```

Is there way to achieve it using Named Query through hibernate as currently in oracle, it is String against Varchar and when searching 123 does not return correct results.?

Answer (score 0):

The query translates automatically to the following:

```
Select * from Table where TO_NUMBER(ID) = 123
```

so you can use that instead.

You can also use:

```
SELECT * from Table where LTRIM(ID,'0') = LTRIM(123,'0')
```

if there are non numerical values in the ID column.

Comment: This query is not working in Oracle. Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: What is the error message? And what datatype is your bind variable in java (should be some numeric datatype)? And are there any values in the id column that are not numbers?

Comment: I have added a alternative solution that is a bit more stable, but the first is what is executed normally if you enter your posted query, so that should work too.

Comment: Error Message : ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: Most likely you have non-number characters in your ID column in database.

Comment: @HPat yeah thought the same, that's why i added the second solution working with characters instead of number - whereas the above mentioned sql query should also throw the error `ORA-01722: invalid number` but perhaps there are enough convertable records that the error doesn't occur thanks to paging.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an error while applying Radagast81's answer then try to convert the number to varchar using `to_char()` as following:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    EMPS
WHERE
    LTRIM(EMP_NAME, '0') = TO_CHAR(LTRIM(123, '0'));
```

You can also use `LPAD` to achieve the same:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    EMPS
WHERE
    EMP_NAME = LPAD(123, LENGTH(EMP_NAME), '0'));
```

Cheers!!

Comment: `LTRIM(123,'0')` is the same as `LTRIM(TO_CHAR(123),'0')` as `LTRIM` is only defined for `varchar2` and `clob` therefore no explicit conversion is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you can assign a default number which does not exists in table, you can use it. see the example below:

```
Select * from Table where TO_NUMBER(ID DEFAULT -999999999999 ON CONVERSION ERROR ) = 123
```